# accessing HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Installer\UserData

Tags: c#, registry, registrykey

Can anyone tell me why I can't access the registry key of `"HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Installer\UserData"`?

if I query the `GetSubKeysNames` of `"HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Installer"` it only returns one value being `"Secure"` ---->  Where are all the other subkeys?

Thanks.

Comment: Please post a few lines of code. How do you construct your RegistryKey instance?

Comment: The real question is "Why are you trying to access the registry key `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Installer\UserData`?" That information is internal OS data.

Comment: @Raymond Chen: One possibility is a crashed install or a failed hard drive where a bunch of ...\installer\Folders were left around with 8dot3 references(1061 of them) that won't let one get rid of 8dot3.

Answer (score 17):

High odds that you are running your program on the 64-bit version of Windows and it is forced to run in 32-bit mode.  The registry redirector will make you actually read the keys in HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Wow6432Node.  And yes, that one also has a Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Installer key but it is pretty empty.  Use Regedit.exe to compare.

The simplest fix is to remove the forcing.  Project + Properties, Build tab, set the Target platform setting to AnyCPU.  If you have VS2012 and up then untick the "Prefer 32-bit" option.  Repeat for the Release configuration.  If you *must* run in 32-bit mode then you can use the .NET 4+ RegistryKey.OpenBaseKey() method, passing RegistryView.Registry64.